Functional inequalities on neighbourhood graphs
Consider an open domain $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^d$, say the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $N$ points sampled i.i.d. on it. One of the simplest possible (unnormalised) discrete Laplacian of a function is given is by
\begin{equation*} h^{-2}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{y \sim x} (f(y) - f(x))\end{equation*}
where two vertices $x$ and $y$ are connected if $|x-y| < h_N$, where $h_N$ is known as a bandwidth paramter (see e.g. Hein et al.). When $N \to +\infty$ together with $h_N \to 0$ at a certain rate, the almost-sure pointwise convergence is guaranteed. On these graphs, known as random neighbourhood graphs, are there versions of discrete Poincare and Sobolev inequalities available ?
A bit of context: I am interested in particle systems on those graphs. For a configuration $\eta_N$ the Dirichlet energy should be of the form
\begin{equation*} D_{2,N}(\eta_N) = \frac{h^{-2}}{N}\sum_{y \sim x} (\eta_N(y) - \eta_N(x))^2 dp_N(y,x) \end{equation*}
for some symmetric kernel $p(x,y)$. Can I expect to bound the $L^2$-norm of $\eta_N$ in terms of $D_{2,N}(\eta_N)$, and what about the $L^2$-norm of the difference between $\eta_N$ and and its localised average (by convolving with mollifiers)?
Does one have references for such type of discrete functional inequalities in graph that could fit this context ?
